# Adjusting Hozan spoke threading tool for different spoke gauges

Tags: spokes, tools

On the hozan spoke rolling tool it is possible to vertically adjust part that holds the spoke, so that spoke would be at the same level as the center of rollers.

[image]

When rolling #15 spokes instead of #14, or rolling double butted #14 (so the part of the spoke which is held is actually #15), is it necessary to readjust vertical position of the spoke to take into account different width of the spoke? Or this difference is to small to require readjustment?

Comment: Do you mean the spoke threader? I’ve edited your question on that assumption but if I’m wrong please revert or let me know and I’ll revert.

Comment: Guessing - have you tried threadding a spare spoke without the adjustment to see if the resulting thread works?   Another option might be to pack the holder with an insert that effectively thickens the spoke, raising it to the desired height.

Comment: This is an excellent question - thank you for asking it.

Answer (score 3):

I have inadvertently threaded many spokes with my Hozan not properly centered vertically -- so much that the threaded ends were bent slightly. They laced up fine in the wheels. Of course I corrected this after I noticed, but I'd say the difference I got due to my error was much more than the fraction of a mm difference you'd get in height by moving between those spoke sizes.

The vertical centering is so imprecise, were I to move to another size, and if I had mine nicely centered already, I wouldn't bother trying to recenter, because I think I'd be equally likely to make it worse.

But I second the notion of threading a spare(s) of different sizes to see if you even notice a difference.